# Acess properties with ID Widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to change a text property in the widget of a class I created, but this widgets were created from a loop
I was trying to access the id, but I could not.
Someboy can save me??

Here is the code:

:

```
    boxin = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    cont = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
    for x in compras:
        boxin.add_widget(Line(text=x, id=compras.index(x)))
    boxin.add_widget(tot)
    cont.add_widget(finalizar)
    cont.add_widget(cancelar)

    boxin.add_widget(cont)
    pop = Popup(title='Carrinho', content=boxin, size_hint=(None, None), size=(350, 500))

    pop.open()

class Line(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, text='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.label1.text = text
        self.ids.label2.text = str(qtd[compras.index(text)])
        self.ids.label3.text = "R$"+str(qtd[compras.index(text)]*value[compras.index(text)])

        def remove(self):
            self.ids.lin.ids.label2.ids['text'].text= "aaa"
```

The function remove would be the button that would change the label2 text of the given instance of the Line class

How i can get it?

```
        <Kv>

    <Line>:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        id: lin
        Button:
            id: menos
            size_hint: None , None
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.47, 'center_y': 0.47}
            width: 20
            height: 20
            on_press: root.remove()
        Label:
            id: label1 #descrição do item
            font_size: 15
        Label:
            id: label2 #quantidade
            font_size: 15
    Label:
        id: label3 #valor
        font_size: 15
    Button:
        id: mais
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.47, 'center_y': 0.47}
        width: 20
        height: 20
```

Comment: You cannot access widgets by `id` unless they are created in a `kv` file.

Comment: Have some way to acess this properties then?

Comment: You could make your own dictionary of widgets.